# Check char size in utf8 encoding

Tags: php

Is there any simple solution to check on how many bytes are stored char in utf8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strlen() returns the number of bytes.
mb_strlen() returns the number of multibyte characters.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a string, then :

- [**`strlen()`**](http://fr.php.net/strlen) will give you the number of **bytes** it takes
- while [**`mb_strlen()`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) will give you the number of **characters** it contains